# Converting cron from UTC to ET in Azure Timer trigger

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

The Cron `0 0 */2 1-8,16-23 * *` in UTC (by default) executes every month 1 through 8 and 16 through 23 every 2 hours starting from 12am (start of the day).

The problem is to convert this cron to execute at the start of the day in ET, since ET and UTC have 5hr difference. How can I configure it to start 5hr after 12am hits in UTC.

Comment: Try this - 0 5 */2 1-8,16-23 * *. This will execute every month 1 through 8 and 16 through 23 every 2 hours starting from 5am (start of the day) in ET

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this CRON expression -
**`0 5 */2 1-8,16-23 * *`** ***This will execute every month 1 through 8 and 16 through 23 every 2 hours starting from 5am (start of the day) in ET***

Update your Timer Trigger with the below CRON Expression or enter this CRON expression while creating new timer Trigger Function:-

**Update the schedule in Function app:-**

[image]

**Locally:-**

**`function.json:-`**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 5 */2 1-8,16-23 * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Timer trigger for Azure Functions | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-python#ncrontab-expressions)

Cheat sheet-
[Azure Functions - Time Trigger (CRON) Cheat Sheet - arminreiter.com](https://arminreiter.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: The second star is a placeholder for minutes as per the documentation how does it corresponds to `Every 5 hrs`?

Comment: 0 0 * * * * once at the top of every hour > Its the hour, For minutes it is - 0 */5 * * * * once every five minutes- As per the MS Doc and  0 */5 * * * * every 5 minutes 09:00:00; 09:05:00
0 0 * * * * every hour (hourly) 09:00:00; 10:00:00; 11:00:00 as per the cheat sheet

Comment: Also, You can add WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE set to your ET as per the Ms Document section- For example, Eastern Time in the US (represented by Eastern Standard Time (Windows) or America/New_York (Linux)) currently uses UTC-05:00 during standard time and UTC-04:00 during daylight time. To have a timer trigger fire at 10:00 AM Eastern Time every day, create an app setting for your function app named WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE, set the value to Eastern Standard Time (Windows) or America/New_York (Linux), and then use the following NCRONTAB expression: